# Is there a way to refactor variables with similar names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const { finalScore1, finalScore2, finalScore3, finalScore4, finalScore5, finalScore6,
        finalScore7, finalScore8, finalScore9, finalScore10, finalScore11, finalScore12,
        finalScore13, finalScore14, finalScore15, finalScore16, finalScore17, finalScore18
 } = this.state
```

Seems like a really un-DRY way of declaring variables. Is there a way to do something similar to `finalscore${x}` and use a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `this.state["finalScore" + x]` to access the variables

Comment: Hacky. I like it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of keeping 18 keys as `finalScore${x}` , you should keep an array like

```
state = {
   finalScores: []
}
```

And then you can access `this.state.finalScores[x]`. You can also loop over the finalScores state array and get the values

Comment: i had no choice due to the way the client wanted data saved, it was either this or another 30 lines of redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the values in discrete properties in `state` in the first place; store an array:

```
// When initializing
this.state = {finalScore: Array.from({length:18}).fill(0)};
```

Then you can readily loop through the array accessing the scores by index.